# Вывод определенных строк из текстового файла

Tags: php

***1. Как поставить ограничение чтобы скрипт выводил данные с 20 - 40 строки на листе?

2. Ссылка должна увеличиваться на 1-цу

`<a href="./top_100/radio_1 
<a href="./top_100/radio_2 
<a href="./top_100/radio_3 и т.д. 
(В данном случае выводит только <a href="./top_100/radio_2`***

```
echo '<table align="left" border="0" width="100%">';


$fn = fopen("./top_100/radio.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");


while($row = fgets($fn)) {
  list( $sPlaylist, $sFile, $sNumber, $sArtist, $sTitle, $sCover ) = explode( "'", $row );

  $sFile  = substr("$sFile", 0, -2);

  $num = 1;
  $last = ++$num;

  echo '<tr><td width="7%"><br/><br/><div id="nau"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank" id="s-nau"></a></div></td><td width="88%" align="left"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank">' . $sArtist . '<br/><br/>';
  echo  $sCover . '<br />';
  echo  $sFile . '<br/><br/><div class="blue skins" id="blue-skin"> Genres: dance top 40 trance house pop </div></a></td><td width="5%"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
fclose( $fn );
```

Comment: `$num = 1;` вероятно стоит вынести из цикла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<table align="left" border="0" width="100%">';
$fn = fopen("./top_100/radio.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");

$countrow=1;
$last=20; //Начальный
$limit=40; //Конечный
while(($row = fgets($fn)) && ($countrow<=$limit)) { //Пока есть строки и пока меньше лимита
if  ($last <= $countrow){//если текущий ряд больше минимального
list( $sPlaylist, $sFile, $sNumber, $sArtist, $sTitle, $sCover ) = explode( "'", $row );

$sFile  = substr("$sFile", 0, -2);

echo '<tr><td width="7%"><br/><br/><div id="nau"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank" id="s-nau"></a></div></td><td width="88%" align="left"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank">' . $sArtist . '<br/><br/>';
echo  $sCover . '<br />';
echo  $sFile . '<br/><br/><div class="blue skins" id="blue-skin"> Genres: dance top 40 trance house pop </div></a></td><td width="5%"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></td></tr>';

}
$countrow++;
}
echo '</table>';
fclose( $fn );
```

Comment: Ставлю: `$num=20; $limit=40;` выводит с 1-21 строку. Нужно с 20 - 40 строку. И по - Ссылка... - подскажи пожалуйста.

Comment: Сейчас, поправлю, чуть по другому надо

Comment: Проверяй, вроде ничего не пропустил

Comment: Ничего не вывел. Пустая страница.

Comment: $countrow++; не туда поставил :). еще разок

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Именно с 20 - 40 строку выводит. Подскажи по ссылке: увеличение на 1

Comment: не совсем понял честно говоря, вроде все норм должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант, на коленке (ваш код для вывода оставил оставил без изменений):

```
$offset = 20; #сдвиг от начала
$limit = 25; #количество записей для вывода

$i = 0;
$count = 0;
while($row = fgets($fn)) {
    $i++;
    if ($i < $offset) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($count >= $limit){
        break;
    }

    list( $sPlaylist, $sFile, $sNumber, $sArtist, $sTitle, $sCover ) = explode( "'", $row );

    $sFile  = substr("$sFile", 0, -2);

    $num = 1;
    $last = ++$num;

    echo '<tr><td width="7%"><br/><br/><div id="nau"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank" id="s-nau"></a></div></td><td width="88%" align="left"><a href="./top_100/radio_' . $last . '/" target="_blank">' . $sArtist . '<br/><br/>';
    echo  $sCover . '<br />';
    echo  $sFile . '<br/><br/><div class="blue skins" id="blue-skin"> Genres: dance top 40 trance house pop </div></a></td><td width="5%"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></td></tr>';
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Скрипт - Ничего не вывел.

Comment: Подскажите увеличение ссылки на 1-цу `<a href="./top_100/radio_1`

Comment: @Serg888 Открытие файла на чтение в начало скрипта добавили?
Увеличение можно сделать через переменную в GET-запросе. Не знаю как у вас настроен apache - смотрите директивы mod_rewrite.

Со стандартными настройками можно в url написать ?page=2
и использовать это число в коде как $_GET['page']